# Qt QTableView paint() event delivered indefinitely which consumes 100% of 1 CPU core

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

After upgrading from Qt 5.5.1 (Ubuntu 16.04) to Qt 5.9.5 (Ubuntu 18.04) code which originally worked normally (even on Qt shipped with Ubuntu 14.04) started to consume 100% of 1 CPU core - paint event is delivered indefinitely and cannot be accepted:

```
void OutlinesTableView::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
    verticalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(fontMetrics().height()*1.5);
    horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView::Stretch);

    this->setColumnWidth(1, this->fontMetrics().averageCharWidth()*12);
    this->setColumnWidth(2, this->fontMetrics().averageCharWidth()*12);

    int normalizedWidth = width()/fontMetrics().averageCharWidth();
    if(normalizedWidth < SIMPLIFIED_VIEW_THRESHOLD_WIDTH) {
        this->setColumnWidth(3, 0);
    } else {
        this->setColumnWidth(3, this->fontMetrics().averageCharWidth()*5);
    }

    QTableView::paintEvent(event);
 }
```

Above `paintEvent()` gets the same event again and it cannot be stopped. Full code listing can be found [here](https://github.com/dvorka/mindforger/blob/a8a9e18ea399007c5ab9283a3791f74c018d2ecb/app/src/qt/outlines_table_view.cpp#L42).

Comment: None of code you put in `paintEvent` supposed to be there. That function supposed to do custom painting with `QPainter` and abolutely no layout adjustments etc. because the rest of higher level functions trigger more drawing etc.

Comment: @AlexanderV Can you please suggest where the code should ideally/typically go? Is it `resize()` or other method? Thank you in advance for any guidance!

Comment: Martin: it could be an event handler as http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#resizeEvent

Answer (score 0):

Originally I suspected stretching mode - if I removed it, then paint event loop disappeared, but the root cause is:

```
this->setColumnWidth(3, 0);
```

To hide column it's better to use:

```
this->setColumnHidden(3, true);
```

Comment: You made the original code less harmful but not more correct.